# Can an elisp piece of code "yield" so emacs doesn't block?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there any way to write something like this without taking over emacs?

```
(defun dumb-wait (seconds)
    (let ((done (+ (second (current-time)) seconds)))
        (while (< (second (current-time)) done)
            (message "waiting"))))
```

(dump-wait 5) will block emacs from 5 seconds.  Is there anyway to write this so it doesn't block?  I just want to be in a loop and check some condition from time to time, and still be able to use emacs.

Thanks!

Comment: `sit-for`?  You can also yield to `redisplay`.

Comment: this dumb-wait function can be used for a prank on a fellow emacser. M-: (dumb-wait 3600). But then there's not many emacsers who have screensavers with no password.

Comment: At the place where I work you will get into all sorts of trouble if you leave your computer unlocked and leave your desk.  A hanging emacs will the be least of your concerns :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(run-at-time time repeat function &rest args)` should do it. `nil` as time means now.

```
(setq my-timer 
      (run-at-time nil 5 (lambda () (message "waiting")))) ; returns timer object
;; or
(setq my-timer
      (run-at-time nil 5 'message "waiting"))

(cancel-timer my-timer) ; use timer object from above
```

**Edit:**

The parameter `repeat` expects a number as seconds, however there's a function `timer-duration`, which you can use instead of the number. It returns the number of seconds as provided with a string parameter. This is somewhat easier to read for big intervals.

```
(timer-duration "3 hours 2 seconds 1 millisec") ; => 10802.001
```

Possible word you can use are defined in the variable `timer-duration-words`.

Answer (score 2):

On a related note, there's no general way to write Emacs Lisp code that doesn't block because the language doesn't have features like coroutines, continuations and threading (yet). Instead, you've got to look for asynchronous inbuilts that do something closest to what you want. Example: `url-retrieve` and `async-shell-command`. Some applications like SLIME have managed to work around this issue and have implemented a sort of threading on their own, while others like gnus are waiting for Emacs Lisp to improve.